# Bootstrap modal-footer does not stick to bottom of modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap model with an horizontal form, and it currently has `height: 80vh;`. I want the modal to be this large and I am happy with it.

The problem is that the `modal-footer` is not behaving correctly. Instead of sticking to the bottom, it occupies a large portion of the space that should belong to the input fields:

[image]

I want to force the `modal-footer` to stay at the bottom, but even after reading other discussions and trying with `padding: 0;` I can't fix it. Following is a portion of the code I am using. I removed some of the input fields to make it easier to read.

How can I fix the stuborn footer?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $('.modal').modal({
      show: true
    });
    return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Click me !</a>
  
  <div class="modal fade in" id="editPackageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPackages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 90vh; height: 80vh;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Package MyPackage</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Package Name:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="MyPackageName">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Other fields here -->
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePackageChangesBtn">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo with your styles?

Comment: Like a fiddle? Never used, I can try :S Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend Plunkr. Here is a base for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/EUqJqov3HuAzykIbH9fi?p=preview As you can see your code probably lacks some specific CSS styles, because issue is not reproducible with just HTML you posted.

Comment: I have tried you code it is working ok, please make a fiddle , that we can see, some other css is making problem :(

Comment: You can also use SO's native runnable http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Added a code snipet !

Comment: Style doesn't seem to be working, what a shame :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `.row` class in the `.modal-body` and put the `form` tag inside `.col-lg-12` class.

check this out i hope this will work!!!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPackageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPackages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 90vh; height: 80vh;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Package MyPackageName</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row">
               <div class="col-lg-12"
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Package Name: </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="MyPackageName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Other fields here -->
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePackageChangesBtn" data-url="@Url.Action("EditPackage", "Package")">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same problem can be solved by many method can you please specify your problem